# How do I get access to variables outside of the function they are defined in?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently creating a simple plugin to WordPress that will enable the use of a [newsletter] shortcode. The shortcode has lots of attributes that can be defined, so I'm catching them all in the $atts array.

Now, I want those attributes to define the look-n-feel of the button. For this I want to add the CSS that it "fills in", into the  tag. To do this, I'm using `add_action('wp_head', 'append_css_to_head')`, however that doesn't work as the `add_action` doesn't seem to fire at all from within the `show_newsletter_signup_btn()` function.

So I tried putting the `add_action('wp_head', 'append_css_to_head')` outside of the function instead, and it fires just fine, but the variables set through the shortcode isn't available outside of the function they are defined in.

So that is essentially what I am asking: **How do I get those variables out of the function for use**?

As you can see from my code below, I'm already using $GLOBALS (I understand this isn't best practice, but I don't know how to do it otherwise), but even that isn't helping.

I've read many threads on this site but have not managed to find one containing a solution that worked for me.

My code below.

```
<?php
add_shortcode('newsletter', 'show_newsletter_signup_btn');
function show_newsletter_signup_btn($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'link_text'                 => '',
            'text_color'                => '#fff',
            'border_color'              => '#e02d7f',
            'background_color'          => '#e02d7f',
            'bg_gradient_color1'        => '#e02d7f',
            'bg_gradient_color2'        => '#a31c57',
            'hover_text_color'          => '#fff',
            'hover_border_color'        => '#e02d7f',
            'hover_background_color'    => '#e7599a',
            'hover_bg_gradient_color1'  => '#e7599a',
            'hover_bg_gradient_color2'  => '#cf236e'
        ),
        $atts
    );

    // Requirements:
    $active_link        = '/newsletter';
    $link_text          = $atts['link_text'];

    // Colors:
    $GLOBALS['nl_text_color']           = $atts['text_color'];
    $GLOBALS['nl_border_color']         = $atts['border_color'];
    $GLOBALS['nl_background_color']     = $atts['background_color'];
    $GLOBALS['nl_bg_gradient_color1']   = $atts['bg_gradient_color1'];
    $GLOBALS['nl_bg_gradient_color2']   = $atts['bg_gradient_color2'];

    $GLOBALS['nl_hover_text_color']     = $atts['hover_text_color'];
    $GLOBALS['nl_hover_border_color']   = $atts['hover_border_color'];
    $GLOBALS['nl_hover_background_color']   = $atts['hover_background_color'];
    $GLOBALS['nl_hover_bg_gradient_color1'] = $atts['hover_bg_gradient_color1'];
    $GLOBALS['nl_hover_bg_gradient_color2'] = $atts['hover_bg_gradient_color2'];

    function append_css_to_head() {
        echo '<style type="text/css">
            a.newsletter-button {
                font-size: 170%;
                font-weight: 100;
                line-height: 1.8em;
                display: block;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 1em 0;
                -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
                -moz-transition: .5s all ease;
                transition: .5s all ease;

                color: '.$GLOBALS['nl_text_color'].';
                border: 1px solid '.$GLOBALS['nl_border_color'].';
                background: '.$GLOBALS['nl_background_color'].';
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom,'.$GLOBALS['nl_bg_gradient_color1'].' 0,'.$GLOBALS['nl_bg_gradient_color2'].' 100%)
            }
            a.newsletter-button::after {
                content: url(' .plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'img/arrow.svg);
                height: 0.8em;
                width: 0.8em;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                margin-left: 0.3em;
                margin-top: -0.1em;
                line-height: 0em;
                -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
                -moz-transition: .5s all ease;
                transition: .5s all ease;
            }
            a.newsletter-button:hover {
                color: '.$GLOBALS['nl_hover_text_color'].';
                border: 1px solid '.$GLOBALS['nl_hover_border_color'].';
                background: '.$GLOBALS['nl_hover_background_color'].';
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom,'.$GLOBALS['nl_hover_bg_gradient_color1'].' 0,'.$GLOBALS['nl_hover_bg_gradient_color2'].' 100%)
            }
            a.newsletter-button:hover::after {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(0.3em);
                transform: translateX(0.3em);
            }
        </style>';
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'append_css_to_head');

    $output = '
    <div class="newsletter-signup">
        <a class="newsletter-button" href="' . $active_link . '">' .$link_text. '</a>
    </div>';

    return $output;
}
```

Edit: And yes, I know there is WordPress-specific code within this, but my question pertains to PHP primarily, I feel.

Comment: Why are you nesting functions?

Comment: @MarkBaker It was originally (and should preferrably be) outside of the primary shortcode function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't variable scoping, it's timing.
The CSS code runs in `wp_head`, while the shortcode is executed when `the_content` is executed.

You'll have to examine `$post->post_content` (don't forget `global $post`) and see whether your short code is in there if you need its attributes within `wp_head`. If it's there (`has_shortcode($shortcode)`), you can either use [output buffers](http://php.net/manual/function.ob-start.php) and `do_shortcode()` or use `get_shortcode_regex()` and its sibling functions from [shortcodes.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/shortcodes.php/) to get the attributes.

Comment: sigh, of course... I may have been at this too long and at the wrong hour of the day. Thanks for the (brutal) reminder of how WP works... :-)